# Internal and external Einstein equation from warped spacetime metric

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

If I have a $D$ dimensional manifold, with Einstein equation
$$R_{MN} - \frac{1}{2}g_{MN}R = T_{MN}$$
and, as a solution, a warped metric, with d external dimension (denoted using greek indices $\alpha$) and n internal dimension (denoted using lower-case latin indices $a$), such as
$$dS_D^2 = e^{A(x)}\left(dS_d^2(y)+dS_n^2(x)\right)$$
where $A$ depends only on the n dimensional internal space.
How can I split the Einstein equation in two separate equations, one for the internal and one for the external space?

Comment: What do you mean by external and internal dimensions for a manifold?

Comment: I mean a manifold which metric solution can be spliced up as the sum of two independent metrics, so that I can think of the original manifold as the product of two independent manifolds (that I arbitrarily call internal and external). In my case the little twist is that the metric solution is not exactly the sum of two independent metrics but I have an overall factor that depends on one of the two sub-metrics. I know this is not very rigorous but this is how it has been explained to me, if you know how to clarify this concept that would be great

Comment: I think I have found an answer to my question. If anyone needs it in the future have a look at this article:
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406039 In particular prepositions from 2.2 to 2.5.